# How to pass multiple parameters to a thread in C

Tags: c, pthreads, posix

I am trying to pass two parameters to a thread in C. I have created an array (of size 2) and am trying to pass that array into the thread. Is this the right approach of passing multiple parameters into a thread ?

```
// parameters of input. These are two random numbers 
int track_no = rand()%15; // getting the track number for the thread
int number = rand()%20 + 1; // this represents the work that needs to be done
int *parameters[2];
parameters[0]=track_no;
parameters[1]=number;

// the thread is created here 
pthread_t server_thread;
int server_thread_status;
//somehow pass two parameters into the thread
server_thread_status = pthread_create(&server_thread, NULL, disk_access, parameters);
```

Comment: Check your code you are declaring  an array of pointers to int and assigning them with int values.

Comment: I did notice that warning. Would it be legitimate if parameters is not pointers and simply an array ?

Comment: if you declare parameter to be an array of int ("int parameter[2];"), then you can pass parameter as a pointer. It is the pointer to first int. You can then access it from the thread as an array.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Since you pass in a void pointer, it can point to anything, including a structure, as per the following *example:*

```
typedef struct s_xyzzy {
    int num;
    char name[20];
    float secret;
} xyzzy;

xyzzy plugh;
plugh.num = 42;
strcpy (plugh.name, "paxdiablo");
plugh.secret = 3.141592653589;

status = pthread_create (&server_thread, NULL, disk_access, &plugh);
// pthread_join down here somewhere to ensure plugh
//   stay in scope while server_thread is using it.
```

Comment: Of course, in code as shown in the example above, you have to make sure that the structure isn't destroyed while the thread attempts to dereference the given opinter.

Comment: The easiest fix is to `malloc` the structure and make the new thread responsible for freeing it. Another approach is to put a barrier inside the structure and have both the original and new thread wait on the barrier before the original thread returns.

Comment: @FrerichRaabe Maybe a stupid question, but how does the structure "get destroyed"... other than a call to `free()` (if it was `malloc`ed) or the function returning (if it was allocated on the stack), is there any other way?

Comment: @The11, I think what Frerich may be alluding to is _reuse._ Some people will populate the structure then pass it to a thread, then populate the _same_ structure for another thread, not realising that the first thread may not yet have made a local copy. This could be solved by arrays of structures, one per thread, or by other inter-thread mechanisms, like a mutex-protected "thread has made local copy of its information" flag.

Comment: @paxdiablo - shouldn't we cast pthread_create argument to void*? (&plug) i mean why it accept any type when the prototype declare that it must be void*.

Comment: @muradin, C will cast to/from `void*` implicitly. You don't need to do it explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

That's one way. The other usual one is to pass a pointer to a `struct`. This way you can have different "parameter" types, and the parameters are named rather than indexed which can make the code a bit easier to read/follow sometimes.