# C++ Passing args to void function

Tags: c++, function, void, args

How can I pass args to this function:

```
int myClass::myFunc(void * aArgs){

    return 0;
}
```

I call it this way:

```
thrd_create(&t, myClass::myFunc, (void*)0);
```

I need to pass multiple arguments to the function, how can I achieve it?

Comment: Well then create a struct which acts as your parameter storage and pass this struct to the function.

Comment: _"I need to pass multiple arguments to the function, how can I achieve it?"_ Use a `struct` and pass the address of an instance of that one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to pass multiple parameters to a thread in C](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223742/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-thread-in-c)

Comment: If you have C++11, you might have the option of `std::thread`, which is standard and makes it very easy to pass any number of arguments while maintaining a regular function signature (no `void *`).

Comment: @chris I don't have C++11, using Visual Studio 2005 compiler. Thanks.

Comment: @ProtectedVoid, I'm not sure offhand whether Boost supports 2005, but `boost::thread` acts very similarly to `std::thread` without need needing C++11 and Boost is at least a de facto standard in many cases.

Comment: @chris I've already tried Boost and it isn't compatible with the tool i'm working with. I'm using TinyCThread at the moment. Thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are plenty of ways. For example:

```
struct Arg_Struct
{
  int m_nArg1;
  float m_fArg2;
  bool m_bArg3;
}
//...
Arg_Struct* pStruct = new Arg_Struct;
pStruct->m_nArg1 = 0;
thrd_create(&t, myClass::myFunc, (void*)pStruct);

//...

int myClass::myFunc(void * aArgs){
   Arg_Struct* pArgs = (Arg_Struct*)aArgs;
   int n = pArgs->m_nArg1;
//...
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! How can I get the args in my function? I've never worked with struct.

Comment: Thanks mate for your help, even being obvious I know nothing about C.