# passing multiple arguments to pthread (including vector arguments)

Tags: c++11, vector, pthreads

I currently have a problem related with the use of pthread.h (since I am still pretty new at it) so I am really hopeful I could get some help from this forum..let's suppose I want to pass this function to a thread that is created with pthread.h :

```
    void test (long int begin, long int end, vector<long int> x)
    {
                    /*do something*/
    }
```

do you know how to include this function into that thread along with all of its arguments?
Or am I even able to pass this into pthread??

And am I able to pass multiple functions with multiple parameters at the same time into pthread?
any help from you is very appreciated, thx

Comment: Declare an appropriate struct, complete with function pointer and argument fields.  malloc one, load it up, pass its address as the pthread_create() argument, queue it to the thread input queue or do whatever your design uses to get the pointer to the thread.  In the thread, make the call through  the function pointer, using the args supplied.  You could free the struct after use, pass it on to some logger or whatever, as long at it gets freed when no longer needed.

Comment: Seeing as you tagged your question `c++11`, the obvious answer would be `std::thread t(test, begin, end, x);`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pass multiple parameters to a thread in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8223742/how-to-pass-multiple-parameters-to-a-thread-in-c)

Comment: Use C++ threads `std::thread`.

Comment: I have done it with `std::thread` but I want to redo my code with pthread if it is possible, because I am  currently learning about pthread too and I really want to know if I can implement the same code that I use with `std::thread` before with `pthread.h`

Comment: I am very hopeful anyone here could give some visualization for the implementation to pthread here, it will really be very helpful for me

Comment: Oh.. yeah, C++.  Sorry, I read 'C' for some reason.  Use std::thread or pass an object instance pointer with a 'run()' method:)

Answer (score 1):

> let's suppose I want to pass this function to a thread that is created
> with pthread.h :
>
> ```
>     void test (long int begin, long int end, vector<long int> x)
>     {
>                     /*do something*/
>     }
> ```

Then we are supposing that you are out of luck.  The entry point function of a pthreads thread *must* have the signature `void *f(void *)`.

> do you know how to include this function into that thread along with
> all of its arguments? Or am I even able to pass this into pthread??

It can't be done *as such*.  But see below.

> And am I able to pass multiple functions with multiple parameters at
> the same time into pthread?

No.

But **you don't need to do**.  The pthreads interface is somewhat awkward compared to `std::thread`, but a single-`void`-pointer argument is sufficient for any collection of arguments and any sequence of functions.  One simply has to create a struct / class containing appropriate members, and pass a pointer to an instance (converted to `void *`).  The thread function then extracts the data, and calls whatever functions are required.

For example,

```
struct thread_args {
    long int begin;
    long int end;
    vector<long int> x;
};

void test (long int begin, long int end, vector<long int> x);
    
void *test_wrapper(void *data) {
    thread_args *args_ptr = static_cast<thread_args *>(data);

    test(args_ptr->begin, args_ptr->end, args_ptr->x);
    // ...

    return nullptr;
}

// ...

    thread_args args{ begin, end, x };
    pthread_t thread_id;
    int result = pthread_create(&thread_id, NULL, test_wrapper, &args);
    
// ...
```

Note well that it is important to ensure that the lifetime of the argument object does not end before the thread is done with it.  That is most often done either in RAII fashion by joining the thread before the object goes out of scope, or by allocating the object dynamically and giving the thread function the responsibility to free it.

It is also important to ensure that the argument object is not modified unexpectedly -- for example, by starting multiple threads in a loop using the same argument object, and modifying the object for each thread.

Comment: wow thanks for the explanation, it really gives me a deep insight about how to implement that function into pthread..
but I have a question, can I pass multiple functions with multiple arguments into pthread??
how can the pthread know that the argument is owned by the function??
unlike `std::thread` it is still obivous to see which function is responsible to which arguments , but it's not really clear for me when it comes to pthread..

Comment: or do I just simply add another functions just like what I did when using `std::thread` ?

Comment: @DeadlyKitten999, I already addressed that question in this answer.  `pthread_create` receives ***one*** function accepting ***one*** argument of type `void *`.  Through that one argument you can provide any number of objects of any type.  And the function receiving them can of course call any number of other functions, passing any arguments to them.  Perhaps I did not make it sufficiently clear that you generally need to write a *for purpose* function specifically to serve that role.

Comment: @DeadlyKitten999 "add another functions just like what I did when `using std::thread`" *How* exactly did you do that with `std::thread`? Please show your code (probably in a separate question).

Comment: Yeah, it's common to declare an abstract class with a 'run()' method that you can override in a descendant class to provide the 'real' virtual function you want the thread to call along with whatever argument fields you need. All the thread has to do is call run().

Comment: You could also add a 'done()' virtual method, called after 'run()', which, unless overridden, simply destroys the instance::)

Comment: @MartinJames btw I did the implementation but it returns undefined reference to test(int,int,int)...can you point out where I went wrong?